# HtmlAgilityPack не видит элемент по XPath

Tags: c#, html, xpath, htmlagilitypack

Проблема следующая, на html странице есть элемент

```html
<div id="highcharts-fsvlmgl-4" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 1094px; height: 300px; text-align: left; line-height: normal; z-index: 0; left: 0px; top: 0.516663px;" class="highcharts-container "><svg version="1.1" class="highcharts-root" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1094" height="300" viewBox="0 0 1094 300"><desc>Created with Highcharts 5.0.9</desc><defs><clipPath id="highcharts-fsvlmgl-5"><rect x="0" y="0" width="1038" height="253" fill="none"></rect></clipPath></defs><rect fill="#ffffff" class="highcharts-background" x="0" y="0" width="1094" height="300" rx="0" ry="0"></rect><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-background" x="46" y="10" width="1038" height="253"></rect><g class="highcharts-grid highcharts-xaxis-grid "><path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 193.5 10 L 193.5 263" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 342.5 10 L 342.5 263" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 490.5 10 L 490.5 263" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 638.5 10 L 638.5 263" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 786.5 10 L 786.5 263" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 935.5 10 L 935.5 263" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 1083.5 10 L 1083.5 263" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 45.5 10 L 45.5 263" opacity="1"></path></g><g class="highcharts-grid highcharts-yaxis-grid "><path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 46 263.5 L 1084 263.5" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 46 221.5 L 1084 221.5" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 46 179.5 L 1084 179.5" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 46 137.5 L 1084 137.5" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 46 94.5 L 1084 94.5" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 46 52.5 L 1084 52.5" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 46 9.5 L 1084 9.5" opacity="1"></path></g><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-border" x="46" y="10" width="1038" height="253"></rect><g class="highcharts-axis highcharts-xaxis "><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 193.5 263 L 193.5 273" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 342.5 263 L 342.5 273" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 490.5 263 L 490.5 273" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 638.5 263 L 638.5 273" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 786.5 263 L 786.5 273" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 935.5 263 L 935.5 273" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 1084.5 263 L 1084.5 273" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 45.5 263 L 45.5 273" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-axis-line" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 46 263.5 L 1084 263.5"></path></g><g class="highcharts-axis highcharts-yaxis "><path fill="none" class="highcharts-axis-line" d="M 46 10 L 46 263"></path></g><g class="highcharts-series-group"><g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-0 highcharts-column-series highcharts-color-undefined highcharts-tracker " transform="translate(46,10) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-fsvlmgl-5)"><rect x="38.5" y="43.5" width="72" height="210" fill="#0b60c0" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-0 "></rect><rect x="186.5" y="219.5" width="72" height="34" fill="#ff9201" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-1 highcharts-drilldown-point" style="cursor:pointer;"></rect><rect x="334.5" y="130.5" width="72" height="123" fill="#2b9920" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-2 highcharts-drilldown-point " style="cursor:pointer;"></rect><rect x="482.5" y="242.5" width="72" height="11" fill="#43ee31" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-3 highcharts-drilldown-point " style="cursor:pointer;"></rect><rect x="631.5" y="228.5" width="72" height="25" fill="#527498" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-4 highcharts-drilldown-point " style="cursor:pointer;"></rect><rect x="779.5" y="236.5" width="72" height="17" fill="#24CBE5" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-5 "></rect><rect x="927.5" y="251.5" width="72" height="2" fill="#ED561B" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-6 highcharts-drilldown-point " style="cursor:pointer;"></rect></g><g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-0 highcharts-column-series highcharts-color-undefined " transform="translate(46,10) scale(1 1)" clip-path="none"></g></g><g class="highcharts-data-labels highcharts-series-0 highcharts-column-series highcharts-color-undefined highcharts-tracker " transform="translate(46,10) scale(1 1)" opacity="1"><g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0 " transform="translate(50,20)"><text x="5" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#000000;text-outline:1px contrast;fill:#000000;" y="16"><tspan x="5" y="16" class="highcharts-text-outline" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round" style="">49.82%</tspan><tspan x="5" y="16">49.82%</tspan></text></g><g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-1 highcharts-drilldown-data-label" transform="translate(201,196)" style="cursor:pointer;"><text x="5" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#003399;text-outline:1px contrast;fill:#003399;text-decoration:underline;" y="16"><tspan x="5" y="16" class="highcharts-text-outline" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round">8.07%</tspan><tspan x="5" y="16">8.07%</tspan></text></g><g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-2 highcharts-drilldown-data-label" transform="translate(346,107)" style="cursor:pointer;"><text x="5" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#003399;text-outline:1px contrast;fill:#003399;text-decoration:underline;" y="16"><tspan x="5" y="16" class="highcharts-text-outline" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round">29.09%</tspan><tspan x="5" y="16">29.09%</tspan></text></g><g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-3 highcharts-drilldown-data-label" transform="translate(497,219)" style="cursor:pointer;"><text x="5" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#003399;text-outline:1px contrast;fill:#003399;text-decoration:underline;" y="16"><tspan x="5" y="16" class="highcharts-text-outline" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round">2.62%</tspan><tspan x="5" y="16">2.62%</tspan></text></g><g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-4 highcharts-drilldown-data-label" transform="translate(646,205)" style="cursor:pointer;"><text x="5" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#003399;text-outline:1px contrast;fill:#003399;text-decoration:underline;" y="16"><tspan x="5" y="16" class="highcharts-text-outline" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round">5.99%</tspan><tspan x="5" y="16">5.99%</tspan></text></g><g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-5 " transform="translate(794,213)"><text x="5" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#000000;text-outline:1px contrast;fill:#000000;" y="16"><tspan x="5" y="16" class="highcharts-text-outline" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round">3.93%</tspan><tspan x="5" y="16">3.93%</tspan></text></g><g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-6 highcharts-drilldown-data-label" transform="translate(942,228)" style="cursor:pointer;"><text x="5" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#003399;text-outline:1px contrast;fill:#003399;text-decoration:underline;" y="16"><tspan x="5" y="16" class="highcharts-text-outline" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round">0.48%</tspan><tspan x="5" y="16">0.48%</tspan></text></g></g><g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels "><text x="120.14285714285714" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="282" opacity="1"><tspan>Direct</tspan></text><text x="268.42857142857144" style="color:#003399;cursor:pointer;font-size:11px;fill:#003399;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;" class="highcharts-drilldown-axis-label" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="282" opacity="1"><tspan>Referrals</tspan></text><text x="416.71428571428567" style="color:#003399;cursor:pointer;font-size:11px;fill:#003399;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;" class="highcharts-drilldown-axis-label" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="282" opacity="1"><tspan>Organic Search</tspan></text><text x="565" style="color:#003399;cursor:pointer;font-size:11px;fill:#003399;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;" class="highcharts-drilldown-axis-label" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="282" opacity="1"><tspan>Paid Search</tspan></text><text x="713.2857142857142" style="color:#003399;cursor:pointer;font-size:11px;fill:#003399;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;" class="highcharts-drilldown-axis-label" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="282" opacity="1"><tspan>Social</tspan></text><text x="861.5714285714286" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="282" opacity="1"><tspan>Mail</tspan></text><text x="1009.8571428571429" style="color:#003399;cursor:pointer;font-size:11px;fill:#003399;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;" class="highcharts-drilldown-axis-label" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="282" opacity="1"><tspan>Display Ads</tspan></text></g><g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels "><text x="31" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="267" opacity="1"><tspan>0%</tspan></text><text x="31" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="225" opacity="1"><tspan>10%</tspan></text><text x="31" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="183" opacity="1"><tspan>20%</tspan></text><text x="31" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="141" opacity="1"><tspan>30%</tspan></text><text x="31" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="98" opacity="1"><tspan>40%</tspan></text><text x="31" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="56" opacity="1"><tspan>50%</tspan></text><text x="31" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="14" opacity="1"><tspan>60%</tspan></text></g></svg></div>
```

Оттуда надо вытащить величину Organic Search. 
Браузером получаю XPath элемента, содержащего эту величину и вставляю в код

```
string uriString = "https://spymetrics.ru/en/website/amazon.com";
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string html = webClient.DownloadString(uriString);
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/svg/g[6]/g[3]/text/tspan[2]");
```

Ну и в результате node = null. 
Подсткажите, что делаю не так?
Вот ссылка на оригинал страницы https://spymetrics.ru/en/website/amazon.com

Comment: Не скажу точно, решит ли это Вашу проблему, но вроде должно: продублируйте слэши (т.е. замените каждый `/` на `//`)

Comment: 1. Вы гвоздями прибиваете все, то есть вы говорите "хочу html/ в нем body/ в нем первый div/ в нем 2 div и тд...", а что если у вас не будет 2-го div'a? Вдруг он станет 4!? Это совершенно не правильный подход!  Вы должны найти что то уникальное в этой строке (класс, id, текст или что то другое) и от этого отталкиваться. тогда ваш XPath будет примерно таким `//div[@class='MyClass']` или `//div[contains(text(), 'Organic Search')]`. Теперь что касается самого HTML - вы дали здоровенную портянку, где я лично не увидел значения этого "Organic Search", а на сайте их аж 3 штуки...

Answer (score 0):

Если DOM будет меняться, то получите головную боль в поиске узла, из-за которого всё поехало. И если захотите не "Organic Search", а какой-нибудь другой столбец? Нужно завязываться на более-менее основоположные и статичные теги/атрибуты. Не увидел для Organic Search заметного уникального атрибута, поэтому в примере ниже завязался на имени "Organic Search", но лучше так не делать в случаях возможного изменения имени, например при смене языка на сайте. Ниже представил универсальный пример, который позволяет вытащить интересующее вас значение для каждого столбца, лишь указав соответствующее значение разыскиваемого атрибута, в данном случае text():

```
"(//*[local-name()='svg'][@class='highcharts-root']//*[local-name()='g'][contains(@class,'highcharts-label')])[count(//*[local-name()='svg'][@class='highcharts-root']//*[local-name()='tspan'][contains(text(),'Organic Search')]/../preceding-sibling::*) + number(boolean(//*[local-name()='svg'][@class='highcharts-root']//*[local-name()='tspan'][contains(text(),'Organic Search')]/../preceding-sibling::*))]//*[local-name()='tspan'][not(@fill)]"
```

Замечу, что если укажете несуществующее имя столбца, то по xpath вы корректно получите пустой массив.
Если смущает длина выражения, то можете вынести в отдельную переменную следующий дублирующийся кусок, по которому определяем позицию существующего столбца с указанной нами текстовкой:

```
string columnPosition = "//*[local-name()='svg'][@class='highcharts-root']//*[local-name()='tspan'][contains(text(),'Organic Search')]/../preceding-sibling::*";
```

и xpath станет выглядеть так:

```
"(//*[local-name()='svg'][@class='highcharts-root']//*[local-name()='g'][contains(@class,'highcharts-label')])[count(" + positionColumn + ") + number(boolean(" + positionColumn + "))]//*[local-name()='tspan'][not(@fill)]"
```